# Does there exist an interval, or more generally a set with non-empty interior, whose Lebesgue measure is 0?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Trying to understand corollary of the Sanov's theorem and the problem basically reduces finding such set.
My first idea was Cantor set, but turns out its interior is empty

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with non-empty interior contains a ball ...

Comment: An interval has Lebesgue measure equal to its length.

Comment: Open balls have nonzero measure, and open sets contain open balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that whenever $A \subset B$ it holds that $\mu(A)\leq\mu(B)$. Now what can you say about the Lebesgue measure of an open set?

Comment: It is always greater than 0? Am I right?